# Magento - determine which xml layout file a page is using?

Tags: xml, layout, magento

I tried reading the documentation but I still don’t really understand how magento's xml layout files work.

In the directory `app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout`, i see a lot of xml files.  How do I determine which xml file any given page on the website is using?

For example, if I were on the home page at `http://mysite.com`, which layout xml file am I using?  What if I’m on `http://mysite.com/hello-world`, which xml file then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

High level version: You're never using just one layout file.

All the XML files are combined in a giant XML file called the Package Layout.

Then, each page request products a number of special string symbols called "handles".

Then, the Package Layout is searched for nodes that match these handles.

The nodes that match are combined into a single XML files called the Page Layout.

That's the layout file any particular request uses.

(shameless, but useful, plugs follow)

I wrote a more [in depth article on this](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates), and if you go to the [Commerce Bug demo page](http://commercebugdemo.alanstorm.com/electronics/cameras.html) and look at the Layout tab, you can see an example of the handles any page request produces, as well as see output for the Package and Page Layouts.

Comment: For those looking for a free extension that accomplishes many of the same things as Alan's Commerce Bug extension, I've found one by Mgt-Commerce. [Developer Toolbar](http://developertoolbar.mgt-commerce.com/)

Comment: I'd like to know how it is determined which handles are relevant for the request. Can I influence that?

Comment: @robsch You're a lot more likely to get an answer if you ask that as a proper question either here or on the Magento Stack Exchange.

Comment: Question can be found here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31519/how-does-it-get-determined-which-handles-a-request-will-use

Answer (score 2):

As a trivial "start" (but please do read Alan's links), if you are on the page catalog/product/view, the layout handle that is loaded by default is `<catalog_product_view>`. Overall, though, it is far more complicated than that. Using layout hints you can find out which blocks and templates make up the page, which is often more useful.

Answer (score 2):

every file to layout is loaded here
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php`
`Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::fetchFileLayoutUpdates()`

constructing xml for page is here:
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php`
`Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateXml()`

People expect them to get an answer here faster than they would get from books and articles.