# Change template page layout on cart page in Magento

Tags: magento

Please help me on this. I want to change template page layout of cart page in magento.

The following is the URL : http://www.wildgoosetrading.com/index.php/checkout/cart/

I want this to look like other pages of category.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd set the template for the cart in your checkout.xml layout file.

In the `checkout_cart_index` section (straight after `<default>`) look for the following block and change the template the cart page is using;

```
    <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

**EDIT**

I know this is the accepted answer but soipo's answer is the better way.  Apply the change to local.xml, don't modify the core layout files, override them using local.xml in your theme's layout.  See http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you please give me full path of this file ?

Comment: It depends what package and theme set up you are using.  If you have set up a new package it will be in app/design/frontend/[your package]/default/layout .  If you are creating a new theme in the default package or editing an existing one it would be in app/design/frontend/default/[your theme]/layout/  .  It shouldn't be too hard to find, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632576/magento-determine-which-xml-layout-file-a-page-is-using

Answer (score 6):

In your local.xml file you can just add the following:

```
 <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
 <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template ></action >  
  </reference>
```

Just change the template to the one you need.

Comment: Changing local.xml is recommended best practice.

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution but can't do it. I have a custom theme, so I have my package name and two different design folders: Default and Shop. When I don't write the code above in my local.xml file in the Default theme then it displays this path frontend/my_package/default/template/page/1column.phtml  but if I write the code above then the path changes to frontend/base/default/template/page/3columns.phtml. How can I point it to my other design folder "Shop" so it can be frontend/my_package/shop/template/page/1column.phtml ???

Answer (score 0):

By using Magento's common `setTemplate` method, the inherent granularity introduced by Magento's own `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` is lost.

Magento deliberately created two methods for doing this: `setCartTemplate` and `setEmptyTemplate`. They handle two separate conditions.

One condition is when the cart has items, the other is when the cart is empty. By calling `setTemplate`, that granularity is lost. That means a cart with items and a cart with zero items will both display the same template, which might be not desired.

More on this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875491/2973534

Comment: someone might come to this answer and see this and have their time wasted... the other answers are in fact correct and the one linked is a separate issue. no granularity is lost by using setTemplate, the linked answer is talking about something else

Comment: If the OP actually wants to change from a 2-column layout to 1-column layout, you are correct. If the OP wants to change the layout of specific cart content, then my answer is correct. I'm challenged to discern OP's real intention.

Comment: i doubt someone is going to come back to a question they asked in 2012, the reason for my comment was I found this question somehow from google and was misled by this answer, which is 3 years older than the other answers, and is answering a different issue, it looks like self promotion of another answer to me, there's very little doubt the OP is referring to setTemplate

Comment: the OP question is pretty poor to be honest!