# cart.phtml override issue

Tags: magento, checkout, cart

I am trying to override `cart.phtml` from `checkout\cart.phtml`  using `local.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>test/cart.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

override works fine but when i try to empty cart it always call my `cart.phtml` instead of `checkout\cart\noItems.phtml`.

when my cart is empty then it looks like
[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the original checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
```

It has 2 template methods - setCartTemplate and setEmptyTemplate.  Add these methods and you should be golden.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen answer by PixieMedia will not work as is. It is missing the essential method call: `chooseTemplate`. Without it the answer will not work. Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875491/2973534 for a thorough explanation; that post contains the proper answer.