# Magento - cart.phtml - Override issue

Tags: xml, magento

I have seen several examples of how to override the cart.phtml, but none of them seem to work in my files.

I have a theme at:

> - app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/

The file is located in:

> - app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/checkout/cart.phtml

I have created a cart.phtml in:

> - app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/template/customsite/checkout/cart.phtml

I have then checked the layout.xml of the theme in:

> - app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/layout/checkout.xml

And see this:

```
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
...
```

I know wanted to override this cart.phtml with my own one and did the following:
I opened the local.xml in

> app/etc/local.xml

and inserted:

```
 <layout>
        <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
                    <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>customsite/checkout/cart.phtml</value></action>
                    <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>customsite/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml</value></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
        </checkout_cart_index>
    </layout>
```

But this is not working. What do I need to do now? Is the local.xml in **app/etc/** the correct one or do I have to use the one in **app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/layout/local.xml** ? I have also seen examples where the  Tag has been left out, the value Tag is named  and the content is set to checkout.cart - Why should I do this if the original xml file says something different?

Would be great if someone can help me out here. Thanks!

Comment: Like it has been answered, `local.xml` is the wrong file to edit. Question is, why did you edit it in the first place? Are you able to provide that information (and maybe some reference)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app/etc/local.xml` file is not what you're after. That contains the environment information for your site.

You can feel free to make changes directly in the theme's layout file:

`app/design/frontend/default/ves_fashion/layout/checkout.xml`

Or you can add a `local.xml` in that folder if you prefer, and make layout updates there.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out, adding layout handles to the `app/etc/local.xml` file is wrong. That is simply for configuration. Your theme should define its own `local.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/{your-package-name}/{your-theme-variation-name}/layout/local.xml`, or your module should define its own layout handles in `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/{your-namespace}_{your-module}.xml`.

Having written that, however, there is an inherent problem with the layout XML provided in your question. As is, those layout definitions will not work. Calling `setCartTemplate` and `setEmptyTemplate` are correct, but they will not work without the essential method call that MUST be called directly after them: `chooseTemplate`. If you view the `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml` file, that method can be seen directly after the first two. This method call alone has been the source of many people's frustrations when modifying the Magento cart templates, made obvious by the number of StackOverflow questions regarding the issue. I've written a thorough explanation of this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33875491/2973534.